# Unix script for loop find error --- find: paths must precede expression

Tags: unix

I am formulating the script so that for loop automates with the find command.
I am getting the error "find: paths must precede expression"

```
++ find alogic/batch/Instrument b/Instrument/Bank b/Instrument/container \
        b/Instrument/Authorize b/Instrument/Common b/Instrument/Confirm \
        -type d -type d '\(' -path alogic/batch/Instrument/BuyerCredit \
        -o -path alogic/batch/Instrument/DebitCard '\)' -prune -o -name \
        '*.cpp' -print
find: paths must precede expression
```

eg:

```
inclusive_directories =  alogic/batch/Instrument b/Instrument/Bank b/Instrument/container b/Instrument/Authorize b/Instrument/Common b/Instrument/Confirm

exclusive_unix_notation=
   -type d \( -path alogic/batch/Instrument/BuyerCredit -o -path alogic/batch/Instrument/DebitCard \)
```

#### Scripts

```
for directory in `echo "$APPLOGIC_EXCLUSIVE" "$BIZ_EXCLUSIVE" "$PACKAGE_EXCLUSIVE" "$PIMP_EXCLUSIVE" "$OTHER_EXCLUSIVE"`
do
    if [[ -d "$directory" ]]; then
        #intially
        if [[ "$exclusive_unix_notation" == "" ]]; then
            exclusive_unix_notation=" -type d \( -path $directory"
        else
            exclusive_unix_notation="`echo $exclusive_unix_notation` -o -path $directory"
        fi
    fi
done
#if processed succesfully added the close brace
if [[ "$exclusive_unix_notation" != "" ]]; then
    exclusive_unix_notation="`echo $exclusive_unix_notation` \) "
fi

# generate cpp files with files to be excluded
for files in `find $inclusive_directories $exclusive_unix_notation -prune -o -name "*.cpp" -print`
do
    if [[ -f "$files" ]]; then
         echo "$files"
    fi
done | sed 's#^\./##' | sed 's/.cpp/.o/' | sort > $OBJ_LIST

exit;
```

Comment: actually the error "find: paths must precede expression" is because of   find alogic/batch/Instrument b/Instrument/Bank b/Instrument/container b/Instrument/Authorize b/Instrument/Common b/Instrument/Confirm -type d '\(' -path alogic/batch/Instrument/BuyerCredit -o -path alogic/batch/Instrument/DebitCard '\)' -prune -o -name '*.cpp' -print

Comment: if i remove the ' (single quotation) the problem is resolved., how can i remove the single quotation..

Comment: You don't need `-type d -type d` (one of them suffices).  That's not the source of your trouble, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are breaking your script likely with use of

```
"`echo $something` another thing"
```

For what you seem to be doing, you can simply:

```
myvar="$somevar another thing"
```

That way you avoid all problems associated with multiple expansion of your commands. And your for loop is suboptimal. Why don't you just have:

```
find some options -print | sed some other options | ...
```

To see only regular files you can add `-type f` to the find command.

Keep simple things simple and try to understand what you are doing. Doing more than needed usually leads to troubles.

UPDATE: besides what I said as a general recommendation above, you need to use `eval find $...`. Otherwise your command line options are not passed to find separately as it expects but as a single option with spaces within. The quotes you see are inserted by bash so you see that the `\(` is passed literary and it is not just a `(` as it should actually be.
Using eval has its own challanges though because it removes a layer of escaping and quoting. So in your case you may need to additionally escape the `*` symbol.

Comment: Hello thanks very much i did using eval it resolved the issue..             `eval find $inclusive_directories $exclusive_unix_notation -prune -o -name "*.cpp" -print`